# Is it possible with tabulator?

Tags: tabulator

I would like to make an order entry form using tabulator.  The table will be :

product id   | product description   | Unit Price | Quantity | Total

The 1st editable column being the product id.  That column will be a JQuery Autocomplete field (or typeahead).  Based on the entry, it will make an AJAX call in the database to list all products matching the entry.

Once validated, it will fill the 3rd column, the cursor will then "jump" to that column allowing to modify the unit price.  After the 4th column will change the 5th column based on the total calculation.

Is it possible to :

- include an autocomplete component with tabulator ?
- have the 5th column calculated each time column 3rd or column 4th is modified ? that column not being binded to the database

Thanks so much, Bye

Answer (score 0):

You can create any editor you like for your table. Checkout the [Creating Custom Editor Guide](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/edit#edit-custom) for full details.

If your plugin needs the element to be visible before it is run then make sure you use the ***onRendered*** callback to trigger any functions that have to be called after the element is added to the DOM.

If you define the ***total*** column using a field that dosn't exist on the row data object, then use a mutator to create the value for you:

```
{title:"Total", field:"total", mutator:function(value, data){return data.unit_price * data.qty}}
```

Checkout the [Mutator Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/mutators) for full details